# Forms and the browser's back-button

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

There is a form on my `page_1.php`. When the user sends the form, they land on `page_2.php` from where they can go to `page_3.php`. At that point, when the user decides to go back to `page_2.php` and uses the browser's back-button, they land on the browser's `page has expired`-page and has to confirm that the data from the form on `page_1.php` will be sent again.

My question is, can this behaviour be avoided? If yes, how can this be done?

Comment: An easy way is sending data through GET ( if possible )

Comment: thanks.. will check it out :)

Comment: If you haven't input type file it should works

Answer (score 2):

GET-request is good when yo **get** data. For example, you filter shop items or search a ticket.

But if you **save** something, then it's better to use POST-request. If problem with back button is crucial, use [PRG pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) to solve it.

Also look at PUT to update and DELETE to remove your data.